# Qubit measurement is followed by instructions. Error code: 7006

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Trying quantum teleportation in
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-textbook/blob/master/content/ch-algorithms/teleportation.ipynb

Succesful runs in 'qasm_simulator', but when switching to IBMQBackend('ibmqx2') I get IBMQJobFailError

[image: see circuit]

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by appending gates onto qubits following a measurement. On qubit 1 and qubit 0, you attach a `cx` gate after a measurementhas already been placed. This will compile on the simulator, but it is not something that is supported on the real hardware.

Comment: Adding link to open issue
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-textbook/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

You should put measurement after all quantum gates. According to the theory, there is no difference whether gates (in this case CNOTs) are controlled by qubits or classical bits.
I encountered the same problem, see solution [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8682/trying-to-build-a-circuit-for-quantum-teleportation-on-ibmq-i-get-error-running).