# What is the right way to teleport qubits on a real quantum computer?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, teleportation

I've been using the teleportation protocol to teleport qubits and then using Qiskit state tomography for reconstructing my qubits.

Using this circuit using open qasm I regularly obtain fidelity 0.9.
[image: circuit using teleportation protocol]

But using the same on a quantum computer returns fidelity 0.5-0.8. Is that normal? I mean, doing tomography implies using more shots and that gives more noise after every measurement.

I also tried doing the measurements at the end but the fidelity didn't improved.

Comment: This may help https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8682/trying-to-build-a-circuit-for-quantum-teleportation-on-ibmq-i-get-error-running

Comment: It may depend on the quantum professor too, try different backends.

Comment: Thank you! But as is see the computational error was before the implementation on mid-circuit measurement. Do you think that because of that my circuit is possible?

Comment: I mean, it runs but I don't know if is normal the relatively low fidelity due to noise in the quantum computer.